# IE7: Item doesn't float

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-float

I am attempting to float a span to the right within an h2 element. In IE8 and Firefox this works fine; in IE7 it is not floating.

The HTML:

```
<h2>
    <span id="spanA"> /*Should be floated to the right*/
    <span id="spanB">
    <span id="spanC">
</h2>
```

The CSS:

```
#spanA{
    float: right;
}
```

Any ideas as to what could be wrong?

Comment: LOL @ question title. So true. :-)

Comment: Why don't you just use divs instead of spans and h2s?

Comment: I could, but for other reasons I don't want to.

Comment: Please post your code, your above code is far from complete (no ending tag, no content, comment isn't an HTML one etc). Yes I understand this is posted as an example but your code should obviously work as should the answers below so there IS sth else ... Did you try (for testing ONLY or for the lulz) `* { zoom:1;}`?

Comment: i agree with felipe, what is the full code? is it text inside your spans or are they images or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The span tag is an inline element not a block level element.  Thus it doesn't float when rendered according to specification.  Have you tried adding display:block; to the css for #spanA ?

Comment: i made a test page for you with a full code sample, i tested it in IE7 using the IETester tool (http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) that allows you to open up and view a page as it would look in multiple versions of IE and it seems to work right in IE7.  What specific version of IE7 are you using?

My test page: http://www.cloudspace.com/test/float-test.html

Answer (score 2):

```
<h2>
    <span id="spanA"> /*Should be floated to the right*/
    <span id="spanB">
    <span id="spanC">
</h2>
```

add this css:

```
h2 #spanA
{
float:right;
clear:right;    
}
```

Comment: Adding clear: right; doesn't seem to help. Just curious- why did you think it would help?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe are you experiencing [this](http://austinmatzko.com/2007/07/25/internet-explorer-7-float-bug/) Ie7 floating bug?

Comment: There is no height set for the containing element, so it isn't this bug. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

so use `position:absilute` and `right:0;`

this is last soluction i hope not in other opction..